# Using Scandinavian letters in libGDX-project compiled for iOS

Tags: java, ios, character-encoding, libgdx, xamarin

I have made a libGDX game that's supposed to work on Android and iOS. The game itself works identical on both platforms, but for some reason the character encoding is off on iOS.

I am creating a Label like this:

```
Label info = new Label("Scandinavian letters: 'æøåÆØÅ'", labelStyle);
```

This works as intended on Android; the fonts contain the needed characters, and everything shows up on screen as it should.

On iOS, however, the Scandinavian letters just disappear (displaying "Scandinavian letters: ''" instead).

I suspect this has something to do with file encodings, but I have no idea which files I need to check, or if there is a setting somewhere in Xamarin for this.

I do know that my Java files go through a lot of conversions on their way to iOS (Java => C# => Mono => Native, as far as I know), so how can I find out where in this process I need to change the encoding, and how?

Alternativey, I suppose this could be solved by using "(char)229" every place I need to write 'å', and so on for the other letters, but that's kind of messy, isn't it?

Comment: Are you creating your font bitmap offline or at runtime?

Comment: Offline. And when using (char)229, 'å' shows up as it should. So I'm pretty sure this has to do with the encoding of either the Java files, or some intermediary files during the (somewhat complicated) compilation process. I have tried several different encodings on my Java files, without success, so I think it's the latter.

Comment: If you log the values or write the strings byte contents maybe you can figure out what charset they're begin converted to?  (Assuming the chars aren't being lost?)

Comment: That's a good idea. I tried, and it looks like they are there. I printed the chars in the String "abcæøå", and I got the following: 97, 98, 99, 202, 175, 194. On Windows and Android, I get 97, 98, 99, 230, 248, 229 instead. Immediately, that doesn't tell me anything, but I'll try to explore different charsets to figure out what happens. If anybody here knows, let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that those letters disappear because of encoding issues somewhere in the process of converting the Java code to Mono binaries.

My current solution is a very ugly one, but it works. So just in case others are having the same issue, this is my temporary solution:

```
public class Letters {

    public static char aa = (char)229;
    public static char ae = (char)230;
    public static char oe = (char)248;

    public static char AA = (char)197;
    public static char AE = (char)198;
    public static char OE = (char)216;

}
```

And then I can write:

```
String text = "Gr" + Letters.oe + "t ombord i en fl" + Letters.aa + "te.";
```